# Change the default color palette in Plotly

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-python

I can change the default theme using:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.templates.default = 'plotly_white'
```

But I how do I change the default color palette?

Answer (score 7):

To add a custom theme, modify `pio.templates`:

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pio.templates["custom_theme"] = go.layout.Template(
    layout=go.Layout(
        colorway=['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']
    )
)

pio.templates.default = 'custom_theme'
```

See more here: https://plotly.com/python/templates/#saving-and-distributing-custom-themes

---

You can also combine themes if you add `"+"`:

```
pio.templates.default = 'plotly_white+custom_theme'
```